# Adding manual version number of site to web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to show version number of site near site logo. Where in web.config I can save this version number? And is this a good idea to save site version number in web.config?

Comment: store in <appSettings> section

Comment: This is my first question on this site. I hope, question is not so stupid.

Comment: I guess this is bad idea to post this question. Sorry.

Comment: It is not necessary to save it in a web.config. Question is really stupid :) Dont mind ha ? You have number of options to do that what you want. If you only want to do this using web.config then you should have told why? Still `to make the question reasonable you have to show what you have tried to solve your problem and where are you stuck`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well seems you would get minuses for this question. But anyway here is my advice:

Store you website version in web.config `appSettings` section, e.g.:

```
<appSettings>
  <siteVersion>v1.0</<siteVersion>
</appSettings>
```

And since you are using mvc add to common _layout view code to display this version:

```
Site version : @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteVersion"]
```

Yes, this is good idea, as this section of web.config is used to store common settings of you app, and changing them on the fly causes IIS to restart you application in order to apply settings. But not sure you would change site version only while deploying.

Comment: should be AppSettings["siteVersion"] no ?

Comment: What should ConfigurationManager be? I saved the version to my appSettings in my web.config but how do I reference it in my view?